# IIS FTP 7.5: Custom Auth Provider not working Error 530

Tags: iis, authentication, ftp, iis-7.5

I have recently install Server 2008 R2 on a new server and want to use the FTP capabilities that are now shipped with IIS 7.5.

Since my users are not windows users, I was using IISAuthManager but this prodiver does not offers home directory on a user basis.

I found this sample http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/669/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-an-ftp-authentication-provider-using-an-xml-database/ to get going with a simple xml based user config. But i can't make it work. It's always gving me

```
Response:   530-User cannot log in.
Response:    Win32 error:   The system cannot find the file specified. 
Response:    Error details: An error occured during the authentication process.
```

I used procmon to get if the xml config file was read with no luck. I don't even think my assembly is being used.

Anybody ever had the same issue ? Basicly, any tips would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The IIS FTP custom providers are a nightmare to debug. In this case sounds like a config error, check that you followed the set up instructions (or manually checking applicationHost.config).  Or post your code (inc config) if you still need help.

Barry

Comment: Thanks Barry but I did managed to get it working but doing a lot of things, not sure everything was needed: Check CALCS, Check user running processes, removed any managed code capabilities to the IIS workers capabilities, isolate the FTP app under is own worker, ...

Comment: And also, for debugging purpose, I end up installing IIS on my windows 7 with Visual Studio so I could debug my dll

Answer (score 0):

```
IIS Manager > Your site > FTP Authentication
```

Probably, you have all Basic and Anonymous Authentication disabled.
One of them should be enabled.